# HttpClient execute method throws java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: java, sockets, apache-httpclient-4.x

Getting 'Connection reset' at client.execute(request) method

```
public HttpResponse createAndSendRequest(Class<? extends HttpRequestBase> httpClass)  {
    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    Constructor<?>[] constructors =  httpClass.getConstructors();
    Constructor<?> ctor = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < constructors.length; ++i) {
        if(constructors[i].getParameterTypes().length == 1 && 
                constructors[i].getParameterTypes()[0].isAssignableFrom(String.class)) {
            ctor = constructors[i];
        }
    }

    HttpRequestBase request = null;        
    if(ctor == null) {
        request = httpClass.newInstance();
        request.setURI(new URI(getUrl()));
    } else {
        request = (HttpRequestBase) ctor.newInstance(getUrl());
    }                          

    create(request);
    return client.execute(request);
    } 



protected <T extends HttpRequestBase> RequestBuilder<?> create(T request)  {               
                String payload = PAYLOAD_DATA; 

                HttpEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(payload.getBytes("UTF-8"));

                if(request instanceof HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase) {
                    ((HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase)request).setEntity(entity);
                }
            }
```

Exception Occurred:

```
Exception Message: Connection reset

StackTrace:

java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:934)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:396)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:355)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at api.restServices.requestBuilder.RequestBuilder.createAndSendRequest(RequestBuilder.java:278)
    at api.restServices.requestBuilder.RequestBuilder.createAndSendRequest(RequestBuilder.java:343)
    at api.restServices.requestBuilder.AssemblyRequestBuilder$AssemblyRequestType.createAndSendRequest(AssemblyRequestBuilder.java:245)
    at api.restServices.RestServices.joinMarket(RestServices.java:400)
    at com.test.App.marketing.ID_1999_Verify_Market_value_and_description_are_displayed_to_MD.test_ID_1999_Verify_Market_value_and_description_are_displayed_to_MD(ID_1999_Verify_Market_value_and_description_are_displayed_to_MD.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: The request is failing while attempting to establish an SSL connection, apparently as a result of the remote side rejecting the attempt.  Not enough data is presented to determine the nature of the problem more specifically.  You might find more in the server's logs, or by engaging a protocol analyzer such as Wireshark to track the progress of the SSL handshake.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: actually the connection reset issue getting only in Jenkins but was working fine in locally.

Comment: That does not tell me anything useful.  To do more than guess, you need to gather primary data.  I suggested appropriate sources for that already.

Comment: Another possibility is sysprop `javax.net.debug=ssl` which gives a usable though rather bloated trace. For completeness the reset _could_ be from a middlebox instead of the remote peer, but _mostly_ those RST the SYN rather than waiting for data.

Comment: @JohnBollinger and dave_thompson_085: Is there a possible way to debug the server logs or response in Jenkins with the Wireshark protocol Analyzer?